# How to get access token without acl in loopback?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I am using loopback 3.0 and datasource as MS SQL server, `"encrypt": true`

When I go to API explorer "http://localhost:3000/explorer/" it shows an `Access Token` by default.

How can I get this access token from an API so one can submit POST / GET from a frontend application (Angular)?

Note: I am not using any ACL at moment.

Comment: What is ACL? (Sorry, I am not familiar with that acronym)

Comment: acl = access control list. its for authentication

Comment: @AlejandroVales check the [loopback docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Controlling-data-access.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call login first, so let's say you have a profile with email: me@fresher.com and password: password, you need to make a POST request to the 
`users/login` endpoint - you can see the endpoint in your explorer and you can try it there.

Then, in your response, you will get the access token which from now on you have to put in your request header: Authorization.

Everything can be found in the loopback docs: [intro to user model authentication](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Introduction-to-User-model-authentication.html) and afer that you can check [making authenticated requests](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Making-authenticated-requests.html), I suggest to start there.

Comment: how to get token which loopback explorer showing in that green bar, without authentication. If I am using MongoDB it work without token as un-secure. I believe that token generated when loopback connect with MS SQL. Is this correct understanding

Comment: A token is generated when a user logs in, a token is related to a user. DB connection has nothing to do here. 
If you just want to get the token from the API, you need to get the one that belongs to the given user. But consider security and maybe try to follow the proper flow